# When some process is suspended, MS Word slows down in opening

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I am using Windows 7 Enterprise Edition SP1 and MS office 2003. If i suspend any process in windows (say notepad or any other) and double click a MS Word document to open, it takes about 20 to 30 seconds to open.
Any idea how a suspended process can effect the opening of a word document?

Comment: Not really the right exchange for this question but.. sounds like it's just MS Word takes a while to load. Does it do this if you already have Word open as well?

Comment: If i open MS word while a process is suspended then there is no delay. If i open the same document from word File->Open then there is also no problem. The only problem is opening the document directly  with double click.

Comment: Not really sure what you mean by suspending a process but it sounds like it's just taking a while to load the application. If you have less than 4GB of RAM consider upgrading.

Comment: Actually process suspending functionality is part of our software. I also tried it on brand new computer with 4GB RAM and fast processor.